# Understanding End point url

Tags: integration, versioning

The endpoint url of the service looks something like this:

```
urn:ttsp.com/is/tel/telecom/UpdateHistoryWSV1.0/UpdateHistoryWSV1.2';
```

Why is two version name of the wsdl mentioned?

Answer (score 2):

Web services can be versioned. If using WSV1.0 version of the WSDL, you would connect to `urn:ttsp.com/is/tel/telecom/UpdateHistoryWSV1.0`. If using WSV1.2 version of the WSDL, you would connect to urn:ttsp.com/is/tel/telecom/UpdateHistoryWSV1.0/UpdateHistoryWSV1.2'. Depending on which one you connected to, a different class or method would handle processing of the inbound/outbound data because the two WSDLs are different and the data streams would therefore be different.

If you connected to the wrong one, there would be errors that the code could not handle and recover from because it would not match the expected format. WSDLs use SOAP and in particular DTD's which are similar to CSS in that there's an opening and closing tag between the start and end of each piece of data. If you have a new 'Data Type' of data that the WSDL doesn't recognize, it wouldn't know what to do with it, thus the reason for the two endpoints.

Note also that the WSDL reflects the structure of your database. If you have Master-Detail and other child relationships between objects, those relationships are reflected in the hierchal structure of the WSDL. If you change that structure in your database, the WSDL needs to change. Using a previous WSDL endpoint to sync data using the wrong WDSL would cause all kinds of errors since the data wouldn't be inserted into the database correctly.

Comment: Thank you . That helped . Question - In SFDC , I would be knowing which version I'm using . Why do I need to mention two versions in the url ?Can the scenario be like version 2 didnot need any changes to be done from SFDC end ?